# jQuery slider randomly shows an image as 2*2 pixel in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, random, slideshow

We're using an image slideshow on our website and it's randomly showing and rotating images that are uploaded in a specific folder. It works fine in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome the slideshow is randomly 'rendering' an image as 2*2 pixels. When I refresh the page the problem is gone. It happens in I think 15% of the time.

Things I discovered:

- When it happens, it's always the last image that is being rendered as 2*2 pixels.
- It happens in about 15% of the time. When refreshing it works.
- Problem is not in the image, it's another image every time.
- I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 7 64 bit.
- In the example below I'm using 3 images.
- It has nothing to do with cache, I deleted it a few times.
- On other pc's I also experience this problem.

See a screen capture here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpxIWvrPA5M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either, update your jQuery.cycle to the latest version 
http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js or - have a CSS override like so

```
#slideshow img{
    width:900px !important;
    height:280px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Spinkzeit! Will try that.